# Packet sniffing with Channel hopping in linux

Tags: linux, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, wifi

I want to scan the WiFi on b/g interface, and I want to sniff packets on each channel, by spending 100 ms on each channel. One of the biggest requirements I have is not to store the packets I get (because of less disk space), my application will parse the packets, retrieve Tx MAC and RSSI, and would construct the list (MAC, Avg RSSI, #Records) at the end of every minute, and then clear this list and start over again.

I've figured out two ways to do channel hop on linux:

*Option 1*: Use **wi_set_channel(struct wif *, channel number)** system call in C, and write the code in C to sniff all the packets

*Option 2*: Use linux command **iw dev wlan0 set channel 4**, and use any language like python+scapy OR C to sniff the packets

I'd like to know which is more efficient of the two, if at all, so that the delay/wait for WiFi interface to switch to a different channel is minimal. I suspect that this delay would mean loss of packet while the switch to a different channel happens, is that the case?

I would also like to know some of the other ways to solve this problem in linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your first question us straight forward, use Option1 and have two threads doing the work - one thread populating an in-memory circular buffer with packets collected from channels and second thread processing them in sequence.  You can determine best packet discarding algo depending on the measured performance of processing thread and other factors if any.

As for the second question, I would go with the above for being in complete control on exactly how you can tune the algorithm rather than depending on canned processing tools.

Comment: Can you let me know why option 1 is better than 2? Since what you are saying can be accomplished using Option 2 also. I would want to know if channel switching in Option 1 is more efficient than the second option.

Comment: It's an opinion, not that channel scan can only be done with option 1. Given your need that you must 'scan' all channels, it is best if you do not thrash kernel with create/destroy processes and thereby spending time in process management that you could have spent on packet sniffing.

Comment: if I asked you which technique for channel hopping is more efficient, which will that be? The reason I ask you this is I can do what you are suggesting in Option 2 also using python+scapy or with some other scripting (or non-scripting) language. Assuming implementing circular buffer, threads etc is possible in all languages, the only difference is the overhead of switching channels. So which will be better? "wi_set_channel(struct wif *, channel number)" OR "iw dev wlan0 set channel 4"?

Comment: I have not seen or done benchmarking myself, but I should have been more clearer in my very first response - "iw" is an external command, not an API.  By invoking "iw", you are starting a new process that changes the channel and exit.  Compare that to an in-proc API call such as wi_set_channel(), however inefficient that C-lib call is, it can't be more expensive than creating a new process to switch the channel.  I hope that clarifies the basis for my recommendation. Are you seeing un-believable time diff between the two methods?

Comment: Thanks Murali, that clears things up to a great extent!